# Show message depending on Mysqli Update Query Results

Tags: mysqli

I have below given mysqli UPDATE query. I want to show different messages depending on update query successful or not.

My mysqli query is

```
$result = $conn->query("UPDATE ads SET adimageurl='$adurllink', adlinkurl='$adurl', adalternatetext='$alternatetext', uploaded='1' WHERE adhash='$adid' AND uploaded='0'");
```

I used this code:

```
if ($mysqli->query("UPDATE ads SET adimageurl='$adurllink', adlinkurl='$adurl', adalternatetext='$alternatetext', uploaded='1' WHERE hash='$adid' AND uploaded='0'") === TRUE) {
    echo 'SUCCESS';
}

if ($mysqli->query("UPDATE ads SET adimageurl='$adurllink', adlinkurl='$adurl', adalternatetext='$alternatetext', uploaded='1' WHERE hash='$adid' AND uploaded='0'") === FALSE) {   
    echo 'FAILED';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` resultmode:

> $result = $conn->query("UPDATE ads SET adimageurl='$adurllink', adlinkurl='$adurl', adalternatetext='$alternatetext', uploaded='1' WHERE adhash='$adid' AND uploaded='0'", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

Then you check if the `$result` is true or false - and follow different code paths.

The reference [page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) gives a good examle: [mysqli query example](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-examples)